# included hook not working for addon projects that depend on other addons

Tags: ember-cli

I have the following structure whereby I have common code used in a number of projects that itself contains other third party ember addons.  I add these third party addons to the `dependencies` hash in package.json so they flow down to consumers.  Therefore I don't have to install them in every consumer manually which would cause a maintenance headache when updating a single dependency.

```
common-code-addon
  - third-party-ember-addon

myapp
  - common-code-addon
```

The problem is that the `included` hook in `index.js` which might import bower dependencies such ass .css and .js code does not work from `myapp`.  What is the recommended way to allow them to flow down properly?

Comment: Which ember-cli version? As of [1.13.11](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v1.13.11) you can use addAddonsToProject.

Comment: Yep, I am on 2.3.  Do you have an example of how to use this?

Comment: There's an example in the [pull request that landed the feature](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/4839).

Comment: Had a look at this but it seems to have the same disadvantage as installing the packages manually into the consuming project.  If I update/add/delete a single dependency, I would then need to manually update each consuming project (both package.json and bower.json).

Comment: Just run the generator and you're in sync.

Comment: How do I run the generator?

Comment: ah, I see.  This should be in the addon blueprint not the root index.js.